# How to convert Firebase array in to collection in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
firebase=new Firebase("https://flickering-inferno-4404.firebaseio.com/User/awosome");
    firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String temp=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>> t=new GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>>(){};
            List<User> userList=dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
            if (userList!=null){
                userList.get(0).getBirthYear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and User Model is

```
public class User {
private int birthYear;
private String fullName;
public User() {}
public User(String fullName, int birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
}
public long getBirthYear() {
    return birthYear;
}
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
```

}

But on line `List<User> userList=dataSnapshot.getValue(t);` I am getting error like

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.chhota.firebasepractice, PID: 8233
>                                                                              com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
>                                                                                  at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:210)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.chhota.firebasepractice.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
>                                                                                  at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this JSON structure at [the location you query](https://flickering-inferno-4404.firebaseio.com/User/awosome.json?print=pretty):

```
{
  "-KCdZSoPFJ91-VKCA4pq" : {
    "birthYear" : 1912,
    "fullName" : "Alan Turing"
  },
  "-KCdZSoeKEYo96gb2GBF" : {
    "birthYear" : 1913,
    "fullName" : "Mohmad"
  }
}
```

*Please add this to you question next time, so that people have enough information to go on.*

Since you're using a `ValueEventListener`, you're getting the entire JSON in your `onDataChange()` callback. This is not a **List** of users, but a **Map** that maps the keys (`-KCdZSoPFJ91-VKCA4pq`, etc) to a user.

So:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, User>> t=new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, User>>(){};
Map<String, User> userMap=dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
for (User user: userMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(user.getBirthYear());
}
```

Comment: Something strange here, a Map is an unordered set, but firebase queries support an "order by" clause, meaning they are ordered, how can this work?

Comment: If you want to maintain the order, you should iterate over the children: `for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { ...`. See the sample in the docs here too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events